# "No versions available" error running LocalDynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, titan

titan version = 1.0.0
gremlin version = 3.0.1-incubating.

Running local DynamoDB in Ubuntu 16.04 terminal gives me an error like this...

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project
>   dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project com.amazonaws:dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend:jar:1.0.0:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:jar:[1.0.0,2.0.0]: No versions available
>   for com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:jar:[1.0.0,2.0.0] within specified
>   range -> [Help 1].

`pom.xml` file look like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan</name>
<url>https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend</url>
<description>The Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan: Distributed Graph Database allows Titan graphs to use DynamoDB as a storage backend.</description>
<scm>
    <url>git@github.com:awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend.git</url>
    <tag>titan1.0.0-1.0.0</tag>
</scm>
<properties>
    <test.extra.jvm.opts>-javaagent:${basedir}/target/jamm-${jamm.version}.jar </test.extra.jvm.opts>
    <default.test.jvm.opts>-Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -ea ${test.extra.jvm.opts} </default.test.jvm.opts>
    <mem.jvm.opts>-Xms256m -Xmx768m -ea -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ${test.extra.jvm.opts} </mem.jvm.opts>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <dynamodb-local.port>4567</dynamodb-local.port>
    <dynamodb-local.endpoint>http://localhost:${dynamodb-local.port}</dynamodb-local.endpoint>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <aws.java.sdk.version>[1.0.0,2.0.0]</aws.java.sdk.version>
    <titan.version>1.0.0</titan.version>
    <tinkerpop.version>3.0.1-incubating</tinkerpop.version>
    <dependency.plugin.version>2.10</dependency.plugin.version>
    <maven.assembly.plugin.version>2.5.5</maven.assembly.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.3</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>2.18.1</maven.surefire.version>
    <maven.resources.plugin.version>2.7</maven.resources.plugin.version>
    <exec.maven.plugin.version>1.2</exec.maven.plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <jackson2.version>2.5.3</jackson2.version>
    <opencsv.version>2.4</opencsv.version>
    <metrics3.version>3.0.1</metrics3.version>
    <commons.logging.version>1.1.1</commons.logging.version>
    <sqlite4java.version>1.0.392</sqlite4java.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <hadoop.version>2.2.0</hadoop.version>
   <!-- <test.excluded.groups> com.thinkaurelius.titan.testcategory.MemoryTests,com.thinkaurelius.titan.testcategory.PerformanceTests,com.thinkaurelius.titan.testcategory.BrittleTests,com.thinkaurelius.titan.testcategory.OrderedKeyStoreTests,com.thinkaurelius.titan.testcategory.SerialTests </test.excluded.groups> -->
</properties>
<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Alexander Patrikalakis</name>
        <email>amcp@me.com</email>
        <url>https://www.linkedin.com/in/amcpatrix/en</url>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <name>Matthew Sowders</name>
        <email>matthewsowders@gmail.com</email>
        <url>https://www.linkedin.com/in/matthewsowders/en</url>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <name>Michael Rodaitis</name>
        <email>mrodaitis@gmail.com</email>
    </developer>
</developers>
<contributors>
    <contributor>
        <name>Zameer Merali</name>
        <email>zmerali@amazon.com</email>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
        <name>Justin Panian</name>
        <email>panianj@amazon.com</email>
    </contributor>
</contributors>
<inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<!-- Libraries -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
        <artifactId>titan-core</artifactId>
        <version>${titan.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
        <artifactId>titan-test</artifactId>
        <version>${titan.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
        <artifactId>titan-es</artifactId>
        <version>${titan.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>${metrics3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Gremlin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for Gremlin console -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-console</artifactId>
        <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <!-- Use the single-integration-tests and multi-integration-tests profiles below -->
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.resources.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>start-dynamodb-local</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>java</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>-cp</argument>
                                    <classpath/>
                                    <argument>-Dsqlite4java.library.path=${basedir}/target/dependencies</argument>
                                    <argument>com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner</argument>
                                    <!-- <argument> -inMemory </argument> -->
                <argument>-dbPath</argument>                
                <argument>${basedir}/src/test/resources/com/amazon/titan/diskstorage/dynamodb/DynamoDBStoreManager</argument>
                                    <argument>-port</argument>
                                    <argument>${dynamodb-local.port}</argument>
                                    <argument> -sharedDb </argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>single-integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>surefire-it</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- <excludedGroups>${test.excluded.groups},com.amazon.titan.testcategory.MultipleItemTests</excludedGroups> -->
                                <groups>com.amazon.titan.testcategory.SingleItemTests</groups>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>multi-integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>surefire-it</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- <excludedGroups>${test.excluded.groups},com.amazon.titan.testcategory.SingleItemTests</excludedGroups> -->
                                <groups>com.amazon.titan.testcategory.MultipleItemTests</groups>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>start-gremlin</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>java</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>-Dsqlite4java.library.path=${basedir}/target/dependencies</argument>
                                    <argument>-cp</argument>
                                    <argument>${basedir}/target/dependencies/*${path.separator}${basedir}/target/dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend-1.0.0.jar</argument>
                                    <argument>org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dynamodblocal</id>
        <name>AWS DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite4java</artifactId>
            <version>${sqlite4java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Just raised this: https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/issues/56

Comment: After poking some people, the issue for me is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue [appears to be resolved now](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/issues/56). Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [blog post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3148), it looks like DynamoDB Local is now available in AWS Maven Repo. So you should simply substitute the `<repository>` node in your pom.xml with something like:

```
<repository>
    <id>dynamodb-local</id>
    <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
</repository>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @mustu - did this really solve your issue? The DynamoDbLocal dependency has been referenced from [the titan project](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml) for ages (slightly different location), so that blog post confuses me. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: http access to dynamodb-local repo will be disabled on Feb 6th, 2017. Have a look at this Github [PR](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/pull/57)

Answer (score 0):

In August 2018 [Amazon announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/) new [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/) with Amazon DynamoDB Local onboard. It does not require downloading and running any JARs as well as adding using third-party OS-specific binaries like `sqlite4java`.

It is as simple as starting a Docker container before the tests:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local
```

You can do that manually for local development, as described above, or use it in your CI pipeline. Many CI services provide an ability to start additional containers during the pipeline that can provide dependencies for your tests. Here is an example for Gitlab CI/CD:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: openjdk:8-alpine
  services:
    - name: amazon/dynamodb-local
      alias: dynamodb-local
  script:
    - DYNAMODB_LOCAL_URL=http://dynamodb-local:8000 ./gradlew clean test
```

So, during the `test` task DynamoDB will be available on `http://dynamodb-local:8000`.

Another, more powerful tool is [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). It supports two dozen of AWS services, DynamoDB is one of them. The isage is very similar, you have to start it before running the tests and it will expose AWS-compatible APIs on [given ports](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#overview):

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: openjdk:8-alpine
  services:
    - name: localstack/localstack
    alias: localstack
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean test
```

Answer (score -2):

Aaahhh! yes, i have resolve it making changes in pom file like this

`<dependency>`
`<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>`
`<artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>`
`<version>1.11.0.1</version>`
`</dependency>`

instead of

`<dependency>`
`<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>`
`<artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>`
`<version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>`
`</dependency>`

Comment: they are exactly the same, just need to assign 1.11.0.1 to aws.java.sdk.version in the properties section